# Xpath set operations - exclude certain nodes (for example with certain feature or features)

Tags: xml, xpath, saxon

I want to exclude certain nodes in a set of nodes. I am using [Mondial database](https://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/mondial.xml) in XML for practice purposes. For example, **I want to find countries where no organization has its headquarters**. [ER Diagram for the database](https://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/mondial-ER.pdf) in question.

This is how I find countries where **some** organization has its headquarters:

```
//organization/id(@headq)/id(@country)
```

When I subtract countries where **some** organization has its headquarters from all the countries, I can find countries where no organization has its headquarters.

I thought of using `except` operator. So, this is what I tried:

```
java -cp saxon-he-10.1.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -qs:doc('mondial.xml')"//country except //organization/id(@headq)/id(@country)"
```

But I am getting this error:

> XPDY0002  The context item for axis step root/descendant::organization is absent. Query failed with dynamic error: The context item for axis step root/descendant::organization is absent

I also tried this:

```
java -cp saxon-he-10.1.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -qs:doc('mondial.xml')//country[not(//organization/id(@headq)/id(@country))]
```

But it only returns the root element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

How can I find countries where no organization has its headquarters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace

```
doc('mondial.xml')//country except //organization/id(@headq)/id(@country)"
```

by

```
doc('mondial.xml')/(.//country except .//organization/id(@headq)/id(@country))
```

Comment: This unfortunately returns `Unrecognized option: except`.

Comment: There's a typo in my answer, which I've now corrected, but I think the problem is that you used this query on the command line without putting it in quotes, so the shell has split it up at whitespace boundaries.

Comment: I didn't test it on Linux but on Windows, if I don't put your xpath in quotation marks, it doesn't work. I have to write it as follows `"/(.//country except .//organization/id(@headq)/id(@country))"`

Comment: Indeed, if you use a shell interface to execute XPath expressions then you will need to follow the escaping rules of the particular shell you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my query with the following one:

```
doc('mondial.xml')//country/name except doc('mondial.xml')//organization/id(@headq)/id(@country)/name
```

And I placed the query in an `xq` file and executed it with the following line:

```
java -cp saxon-he-10.1.jar net.sf.saxon.Query query.xq
```

And it did work. But I still do not know how I can get it working in a pure command line fashion, like my first original query.